# Jquery Zoom Elevate plugin - Se puede implementar con un slideshow y mouse whell?

Tags: jquery

Necesito encontrar este plugin, teniendo una imagen con el mouse me permita hacer zoom IN/OUT, mostrando un area en especifica.

Aqui les dejo un ejemplo de una pagina que utiliza esa metodologia en las imagenes:
http://www.auctiva.com/hostedimages/showimage.aspx?gid=1911616&image=851553898&images=851553907,851553898&formats=0,0&format=0

Colocar el mouse encima de la imagen y mover la rueda del mouse para que haga el zoom IN/OUT.

Gracias...

Comment: Esta pregunta no es realmente sobre programación. Stackoverflow Es para preguntas sobre problemas específicos de programación y no para pedir recomendaciones o ayuda buscando plugins, tutoriales o libros.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, en ningun momento estoy pidiendo opiniones sobre el plguin, solo estoy preguntando quine ha utilizado un plguin que cumpla las especificaciones que comento no mas. SI hay algun problema con la pregunta digamelo y la cierro enseguida

Comment: "_solo estoy preguntando quine ha utilizado un plguin que cumpla las especificaciones que comento no mas_" <-- esto es la definición de una pregunta basada en opiniones. Puedes obtener 1.000 respuestas diferentes todas igualmente válidas con plugins que cumplan esos requisitos.

Comment: Exacto eso e slo que quiero que me den opciones de plugin que cumplan esas caracteristicas... sera ahcer preguntas con respuestas unicas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el plugin de [elevatezoom](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom).

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){  
  
  $("#zoom").elevateZoom({
    
    scrollZoom: true,
    zoomType: "lens",
    containLensZoom: true,
    lensShape: "round",
    lensSize: 150,
    lensFadeIn: 300,
    lensFadeOut: 300,
    borderSize: 2  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>

<img id="zoom" src="http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/abstract/dummy-400x400-Mosque.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/abstract/dummy-1600x1600-Mosque.jpg">
```

Comment: Y también [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) para el carrusel de arriba

Comment: @MiguelMaury - Y cual seria las especificaciones deseadas?

Comment: Ese plugin ya te lo habia chequeado pero no se ajusta  las especificaciones deseadas. Lo mas parecido es este ejemplo Lens Zoom, pero la idea no es uqe se haga el zoom en otro div sino que tenga como un lente y dentor del lente se haga el zoom. 

Asi tal cual lo hace este plugin: (http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/zoome-jquery-image-zoom-effect-plugin/full_screen_preview/2973067?_ga=1.7444208.399188378.1482245251)

Solo que es pago y necesito uno libre

Comment: @MiguelMaury - haz probado ejecutar aquí el código? Tienes que presionar el botón `Ejecutar` y verás que es eso lo que estás buscando...

Comment: @aldanux muchisimas gracias eso era lo que buscaba, no habia visto el ejemplo me fui directamente a la pagina del plugin